# Conversion From DB2 to Oracle:

Tags: sql, database, oracle, db2, migration

I am working on DB2 to Oracle Conversion, I want to know what is this TABLE keyword means in DB2 or how to convert it in oracle ?? This code is a part of a tabular function.

```
SELECT   A.A_REQUESTER,
         A.A_TIME,
         A.A_NAME,
         F.LOCAL,
         F.MSGS
FROM STRTOK_SPLIT_IS_TABLES A( A_REQUESTER,
                               A_TIME,
                               A_NAME, 
                               A_CODE ),
TABLE( SYSPROC.GET_MSGS(
       INLOCAL,
       A.A_CODES,
( SELECT TOKEN FROM STRTOK_SPLIT_TABLES_USHARE B
  WHERE A.A_REQUESTER = B.REQUESTER
  AND A.A_TIME      = B.ETIME
  AND A.A_NAME       = B.NAME
  AND B.ORDINAL=1 ) ) 
    ) F;
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code should be doing.

Comment: Did a Google on `SYSPROC.GET_MSGS` and got https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0054504.html which I'm guessing manipulates/extracts data from XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with DB2, but if it has the same meaning as Oracle, it is used to "cast" a type object or a function call to a table so it can be referenced in a SQL statement.

The (Oracle) example below joins the type [SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcicnstnts.htm) to DUAL. The type SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST is defined as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST FORCE AS VARRAY(32767) OF VARCHAR2(4000);
```

Using the TABLE keyword allows you to reference the type as if it was an actual table.  If you are on Oracle 19, the TABLE keyword is no longer needed.

#### Query

```
SELECT *
  FROM DUAL,
       TABLE (sys.odcivarchar2list ('tab_val_1',
                                    'tab_val_2',
                                    'tav_val_3',
                                    'tab_val_4'));
```

#### Result

```
   DUMMY    COLUMN_VALUE
________ _______________
X        tab_val_1
X        tab_val_2
X        tav_val_3
X        tab_val_4
```

Comment: I know it's late but thanks.